# How can I make a CAEmitterCell fade out at the end of its lifetime?

Tags: ios, core-animation

I'm animating some particles and rather than have then just disappear at the end of their lifetime I'd like them to fade out.

I have a `CAEmitterCell` defined with a lifetime of 35.0. I don't want to just have the particle fade out over the full duration of the particle lifetime. I only want it to fade out at the end. Perhaps the last 2 or 3 seconds.

Answer (score 9):

For the `CAEmitterCell`'s `color` property, set the alpha value to `lifetime * alphaSpeed` (where alphaSpeed is -1.0/fadeOutDuration).

So for a lifetime of 35.0 and a fadeOutDuration of 2.0, alphaSpeed would be -0.5, and alpha would be 17.5.

There are a couple caveats:

1. This only works if your cells are supposed to start at full alpha.
2. You'll have to set `CAEmitterCell`'s color property using a `CGColorRef` created with `CGColorCreateCopyWithAlpha`. Both `UIColor` and `CGColorCreate` clamp their values to a maximum of 1.0. For whatever reason, `CGColorCreateCopyWithAlpha` doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Just came across this in the docs which might point in the right direction:

> name
> The name of the cell.
>
> @property(copy) NSString *name
> Discussion
> The cell name is used when constructing animation key paths that reference the cell. Defaults to nil.
>
> For example, adding an animation to a cell’s enclosing layer with the a keypath such as emitterCells.myCellName.redRange would animate the redRange propery of the cell in the layer’s emitterCells array with the name myCellName.
>
> Availability
> Available in Mac OS X v10.6 and later.
> Declared In
> CAEmitterCell.h

I gather you still add the animation to the layer but with a key path that references a part of that layer - in this case the cell's property.  Is there an alpha property exposed for cells?

Comment: On second thought, this would affect the whole emitter, not the individual particles. My next guess would be to look into the very loosely typed and "animatable" `content` property.